# Finding the opposite of condition (using R tidyverse) in order to split dataset in 2

Tags: r, dplyr, dataset, logical-operators

I'm trying to split my dataset (296 rows) in two, the first part will have some conditions and the other is only the rest of the dataset that does not match the conditions.

I did this and found 81 rows for the first part :

```
cardio = donnees %>%
  select(`Nausées/vomissements`,Vertige,Nystagmus,`Ataxie:Démarche ébrieuse`,`Motif si pas HINTS`,
         Alcool,Tabac,`atcd neuro`,Dyslipidémies,Diabète) %>%
  filter(Alcool == "Yes" |
         Tabac == "Yes"|
         `atcd neuro` == "3" |
         Dyslipidémies == "Yes"|
         Diabète == "Yes")
```

Then I simply use "!" to find the rest, but unfortunately I only got 77 rows instead of the 215 expected,

```
donnees %>%
  select(`Nausées/vomissements`,Vertige,Nystagmus,`Ataxie:Démarche ébrieuse`,`Motif si pas HINTS`,
         Alcool,Tabac,`atcd neuro`,Dyslipidémies,Diabète) %>%
  filter(!(Alcool == "Yes" |
           Tabac == "Yes" |
           `atcd neuro` == "3" |
           Dyslipidémies == "Yes" |
           Diabète == "Yes" ))
```

If someone can help? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the brackets, you can replace the `==` and `|` symbols with `!=` and `&`:

```
donnees %>%
  select(`Nausées/vomissements`,Vertige,Nystagmus,`Ataxie:Démarche ébrieuse`,`Motif si pas HINTS`,
         Alcool,Tabac,`atcd neuro`,Dyslipidémies,Diabète) %>%
  filter(Alcool != "Yes" &
           Tabac != "Yes" &
           `atcd neuro` != "3" &
           Dyslipidémies != "Yes" &
           Diabète != "Yes" )
```

Edit: you can use the `anti-join` function:

```
cardio = donnees %>%
  select(`Nausées/vomissements`,Vertige,Nystagmus,`Ataxie:Démarche ébrieuse`,`Motif si pas HINTS`,
         Alcool,Tabac,`atcd neuro`,Dyslipidémies,Diabète) %>%
  filter(Alcool == "Yes" |
         Tabac == "Yes"|
         `atcd neuro` == "3" |
         Dyslipidémies == "Yes"|
         Diabète == "Yes")

others <- dplyr::anti_join(donnees, cardio)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I tried this aswell before but the output is 77 rows (exactly the same as my try)

Comment: Could you provide a sample using `dput` please?

Comment: Can I show you some screenshots? I do not really know how to use dput ?

Comment: @ElyséBarbaza check-out the edit i just made. Plus, here the link to make your example reproductible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you a lot of your help it worked, I'm really grateful
Have a wonderful evening ! This platform is amazing

Comment: Don't forget to validate the answer! Welcome to SO! Enjoy @ElyséBarbaza

Answer (score 2):

I `anti_join` method suggested by @MonJeanJean should work. But if incase it doesn't, here is a bit different approach, the idea is to create a index column and exclude which ever you don't require (reminiscent of mysql days).

```
donnees$index = 1:nrow(donnees)

cardio = donnees %>%
  select(`Nausées/vomissements`,Vertige,Nystagmus,`Ataxie:Démarche ébrieuse`,`Motif si pas HINTS`,
         Alcool,Tabac,`atcd neuro`,Dyslipidémies,Diabète, index) %>%
  filter(Alcool == "Yes" |
         Tabac == "Yes"|
         `atcd neuro` == "3" |
         Dyslipidémies == "Yes"|
         Diabète == "Yes")

cardio_required = cardio[-index, ]
```

This will give you the 215 rows

Comment: I thought to this method, but for me it can be too ressources-expensives as soon as you have a lot of row. But it works well for this little sample!

Comment: Thanks for this other method !